# Plasma Integration failed to connect

Tags: kubuntu, kde, chromium, plasma-5

I've installed Plasma Integration from Chrome Web Store to Chromium - Version 78.0.3904.70 (Official Build) snap (64-bit). I get the message: "Failed to connect to native host plasma". But the extension works well in Google Chrome and Firefox.

Do you have any ideas on how to fix it? It worked in Kubuntu 19.04 - the problems started after the clean reinstall to Kubuntu 19.10. Thanks.

System Specifications:

- Operating System: Kubuntu 19.10
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.16.5
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.62.0
- Qt Version: 5.12.4
- Kernel Version: 5.3.0-19-generic
- OS Type: 64-bit
- Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz
- Memory: 15,4 GiB of RAM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the chromium in 19.10 has been transitioned to a snap.

The reason is the same as [this other bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1741074) affecting chromium, and that the Firefox snap also has the same issue.